# Inversive geometry with regard to circumscribed circle of a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $k$ = $k$($O$, $r$) be circumscribed circle for triangle Δ$ABC$ and let $m$ be perpendicular bisector of segment $BC$. Notice points: $m$ ∩ $p(A, C)$ = {$Q$}, $m$ ∩ $p(A, B)$ = {$P$} and let $ψ$<sub>k</sub> be inversion with regard to circle $k$. Prove that $ψ$<sub>k</sub>($P$) = $Q$.

So far I've deduced that $O$, $P$ and $Q$ are collinear points and noticed the point $T$, which is the intersection point of a tangent from $P$ on $k$. I've spent several days on this problem, trying to prove that $TQ$ ⊥ $p(P,Q)$ by using power of a point or by using four, basic, inversion properties. I've seen at least three other problems regarding this idea, but I was not able to solve any of them. I would, indeed, appreciate any help.

Comment: What does $p(A,C)$ mean?

Comment: I apologize for that. I was not aware it, might, not be standard notation. $p(A, C)$ is the line through points $A$ and $C$.

Comment: Thanks!  Also, when you write "tangent from $P$ on $k$" you are implicitly assuming that $P$ is outside the circumcircle, which confused me initially (though certainly one of $P$ and $Q$ is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT.

Angles $\angle OAQ$ and $\angle OPA$ are equal. Thus triangles $OAQ$ and $OPA$ are similar and $OP\cdot OQ=OA^2$.

Comment: Thank you. It was, probably, simple for you, but very instructive for me.